# Input files path and return a list of files on tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to use Tkinter for the code below. My goal is to use the entry widget to input the path of a folder and click a button to search and return the list of "pdf" files from the folder(see below). The python code works fine but I'm not sure how to create it in tkinter.

```
from os import listdir,mkdir,startfile
from os.path import isfile, join,exists
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger
import os

# Input file path and print the pdf files in that path
path = input("Enter the folder location: ")
pdffiles = [f for f in listdir(path) if isfile(join(path, f)) and '.pdf' in f]
print('\nList of PDF Files:\n')
for file in pdffiles:
    print(file)
```

Output:

```
List of PDF Files:

file1.pdf.pdf
file2.pdf.pdf
file3.pdf.pdf
file4.pdf.pdf
```

Comment: Hint: Take a look at the functions and classes in the [`tkinter.filedialog`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dialog.html#module-tkinter.filedialog) module.

Comment: did you use tkinter befor? Do you know how to create anything in tkinter? If  you didn't use tkinter before then maybe better find some tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

To get text you could use `tkinter.simpledialog.askstring(title, prompt)`

[image]

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import simpledialog

root = tk.Tk()  # manually create main window
root.withdraw() # hide main window

path = simpledialog.askstring('Directory', 'name:')

root.destroy()  # destroy main window

if not path:
    print('Canceled')
else:    
    print(path)
```

But for directory can be more useful `tkinter.filedialog.askdirectory(...)`

[image]

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog

root = tk.Tk()  # manually create main window
root.withdraw() # hide main window

path = filedialog.askdirectory()

root.destroy()  # destroy main window

if not path:
    print('Canceled')
else:    
    print(path)
```

---

```
import tkinter as tk
#from tkinter import simpledialog
from tkinter import filedialog
import os

root = tk.Tk()  # manually create main window
root.withdraw() # hide main window

#path = simpledialog.askstring('Directory', 'name:')
path = filedialog.askdirectory()

root.destroy()  # destroy main window

if not path:
    print('Canceled')
else:    
    print(path)

    pdffiles = [fn for fn in os.listdir(path) if fn.lower().endswith('.pdf') and os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, fn))]

    print('\nList of PDF Files:\n')
    for filename in pdffiles:
        print(os.path.join(path, filename))
```